# No visible @interface for 'UIAlertController' declares the selector 'initWithTitle:message:delegate:cancelButtonTitle:otherButtonTitles:'

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
    UIAlertController *alert = [[UIAlertController alloc] initWithTitle: alertString message:nil
delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
```

I'm having this error:

```
No visible @interface for 'UIAlertController' declares the selector 'show'
```

and this :

> No visible @interface for 'UIAlertController' declares the selector 'initWithTitle:message:delegate:cancelButtonTitle:otherButtonTitles:'

Comment: You are confusing UIAlertView and UIAlertController.

Comment: What @Kreiri said is correct. You are getting the error, because the class you are using does not have a show() method. That error message is the equivalent of an unrecognized selector, does not have member, and similar errors in other languages.

Comment: ok. thank you. im just a newbie here

Answer (score 1):

This true of step to declare `UIAlertController`

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:title message:message preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

// add action button
UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:actionTitle style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];

[alertController addAction:okAction]; // add action button to alert controller



// present alert controller in view
[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```